# Calling Date() from JavaScript. Where does that method come from?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to start learning JavaScript instead of allways copying it. I know this probably is super simple, but where does `Date()` come from? Why can I call it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function displayDate() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First JavaScript</h1>
<p id="demo">This is a paragraph.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="displayDate()">Display Date</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is your local system(your pc or device) date. Javascript library gives you the access. Its a global one

Comment: It is the property of the global window Object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Date()` is a built in object, declared in the global scope, just like `Math`, `Array` etc.

You can read more about this under section `4.2 Language Overview` in the [ECMA specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf). Quote:

> ECMAScript defines a collection of built-in objects that round out the
>   definition of ECMAScript entities. These built-in objects include the
>   global object, the Object object, the Function object, the Array
>   object, the String object, the Boolean object, the Number object, the
>   Math object, the Date object, the RegExp object, the JSON object, and
>   the Error objects Error, EvalError, RangeError, ReferenceError,
>   SyntaxError, TypeError and URIError.

Comment: Shouldn't it be more appropriate to call `Date()` an `object`?

Comment: @radbyx http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf

Comment: @Abhilash—`Date` is a built–in object, `Date()` is an expression calling Date as a function. Please don't reference W3Schools, ECMA-262 is the definitive reference for language features, MDN and MSDN are good for examples and descriptions of behaviour for implementations in wide use.

Comment: @RobG, actually, it's a builtin type constructor, and since all functions are object, it's also an object (but that's secondary).

Comment: @Alexn oh so ECMAScript has a collection with all these good objects. But where is the code/DLL/framework actually located on the machine?

Comment: @RobG, I don't quite understand this attitude towards W3Schools. That place has helped me a lot (it still does sometimes) when I had no clue what js is all about. Also, I genuinely wish to know why referencing W3S is a bad idea. ECMA can be overkill when you are a beginner.

Comment: @alexn, didn't know about it. Although once beyond the beginner stage I have liked W3S less and less, but I have been guilty of pointing people to the resource a lot. While I can't begin to hate W3S overnight (I still believe it helped me a lot initially), I will have to rethink about pointing others there.

Comment: Well my example is from w3schools and look what i gave me. It open my eyes for ECMA :)

Comment: @SeanKinsey—the [Date object](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9) is a [built–in object](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.7) that is included in the [built–in object section](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15). It's also a [built–in function](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.25) and can be called as a [function](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.2) or [constructor](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3). Its Type is Object, there's no function Type, though `typeof Date == 'function'`.

Answer (score 2):

It's the [constructor of the Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), which is one of the [global objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects) available in JavaScript.

**Edit:** Please note that your code sample does not use `new`, thus it isn't being used as constructor--it'll return a string rather than an object.

Comment: Thanks. Now I know where to read more about it, and I am going too. But do you know where the code exactly is on the computer? Is it still wihtin my code on is it global as in within the computer somewhere? :) In C# I can reference another DLL and I know exactly where it is, that's what I am looking for here too.

Comment: Well, I'm sure the DLL is somewhere among your browser's program files. But JavaScript is an interpreted language. I don't know what you have in mind but thinking about it in terms of DLLs makes little sense.

Comment: I have read about the global scope and the interpretation language now. Can you find the DLL or lead me in some direction?

Comment: There're lots of JavaScript implementations. Are you talking about Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Internet Explorer, Node.js...?

Answer (score 1):

The [Date object](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.2.1) is described in the [ECMAScript specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-A.5). Can also try [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for more information and examples.

Answer (score 1):

Date() is a built in object, declared in the global scope

Please remember that value of date is client side value which come from user pc not server date

Comment: Ok thanks. Then I guess the `Date object` can be found on the client computer and not within my code, if that make any sense?